# How do you hide images from posts only

Tags: images

As the title says I want to keep images on pages and hide them from posts on my [site](http://www.thezenapproach.com) . How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a css solution. Pages and posts have different `body_class`es, so you should be able target them with `page` and `post` respectively. Your CSS would look something like this:

```
.post img {
    display: none
}
```

Comment: please mark the question as solved if this was working solution.

Comment: This (to me) is both correct _and_ wrong. It's absolutely correct if you truly to wish to just **hide** the image. However, this will still produce an HTTP request that has no purpose and technically increases your page load time. If you happen to have a post with a handful of large, hi-res images your page load time could potentially take a beating for images that aren't going to show anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could check whether your "Post Type" is a Page or a Post using [this function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types) ( link to the Codex at Post Types )

Also this function will come in handy to get the current post type:
get_post_type, doc [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type)

Edit: The CSS Solution of m0r7if3r is also elegant. But is the image actually loading ( by the browser ) with display:none ? Meaning that if it is loaded, the website will become heavier for something not visible. But I'm not sure about the behavior of image loading with css display:none. Any thought on that?